# How accessible is Fullcalendar?

Tags: accessibility, fullcalendar, tooltip

I'm having problems making FullCalendar fully accessible. I'm using the default month view and can't access the next, previous, and today buttons on the top right without using a mouse. If I run a screen reader, I can access those buttons but not without running the screen reader.

And on another note, I currently am using tool tips that pop up when you mouse over an event title to display more information. If anyone has any tips on how to make those accessible to a screen reader or accessible without a mouse, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the buttons, I would advice that you write new buttons if accessibility is important. These buttons you could then hook up to your own javascript functions that moves to previous and next. 
[Check out this documentation example](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/next/)

Regarding the second problem, I think that's the same problem not just for physically impaired but also for things like mobile browsers. My tip would be to avoid `onmouseover` if the information that appears is really important.

Comment: Is there no way to just tab through to the today, next, and previous buttons?